# onclick attribute is not being registered

Tags: html, dom, ecmascript-6

```
const googleDiv = function(){

  const container = document.createElement('div');
  const btnEle = document.createElement('button');
  btnEle.type = "button";
  btnEle.className = "link-btn";
  btnEle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("(Unlink)"));
  btnEle.onclick = "unlinkGoogle()";
  container.appendChild(btnEle);
  container.id = "google-linked-container";
  return container;
};
```

When I create a button via this method, the button appears in the DOM no problem and the button type and classes are as expected, but there is no onclick attribute. Why?

P.S.
`btnEle.addEventListener("click", () => { console.log("clicked!"); });` doesn't work either.

**Update**
I have replicated it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fs1xhgnm/2/

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle @Ashley ?

Comment: Seems to work fine with `addEventListener`. https://jsfiddle.net/fs1xhgnm/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should assign your handler as a function, instead of string. Also, try to assign onclick handler after the element is appended.

```
container.appendChild(btnEle);
btnEle.onclick = unlinkGoogle;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a reference to the function, either with the onclick, or the better addEventListener

```js
const googleDiv = function() {

  const container = document.createElement('div');
  const btnEle = document.createElement('button');
  btnEle.type = "button";
  btnEle.className = "link-btn";
  btnEle.appendChild(document.createTextNode("(Unlink)"));
  btnEle.addEventListener('click', unlinkGoogle);
  container.appendChild(btnEle);
  container.id = "google-linked-container";

  return container;
};

function unlinkGoogle() {
  console.log('clicked');
}

document.body.appendChild(googleDiv());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a string as the function. You can use `addEventListener`.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3dfmmh5m/) to explain what I mean.